# Text animation not occurring on event emission (or event not emitting)

Tags: aframe

I have a text element and a skybox in my scene. When the scene initialises, I want the text to animate its position once.

```
<!-- scene elements -->
<a-scene coogee2006-scene embedded style="width:100%;height:400px;">
    <a-assets>
        <img
            id="coogee2006"
            src="/assets/vr/sydney-coogee-3-peter-gawthrop.jpg"
            preload="auto">
        <audio
            id="beachsound"
            src="/assets/vr/beach1.wav"
            preload="auto">
    </a-assets>

    <a-sky src="#coogee2006"
        rotation="0 -90 0">
    </a-sky>

    <!-- text animates in on startup (see searise_vr.js) -->
    <a-text
        id="coogee2006-text"
        value="Coogee, Sydney\n2006"
        position="5 12.5 -50"
        rotation="0 -15 0"
        scale="20 20 20"
        visible="true"
        text="anchor:align;alphaTest:0.2;width:5;
        value:COOGEE, SYDNEY\n2006;
        zOffset:0;color:#000;font:exo2bold"
        sound="src:#beachsound;autoplay:true;loop:true;volume:20;">
        <a-animation
            attribute="position"
            dur="3000"
            begin="coogeetour"
            to="12.5 12.5 -50"
            easing="ease-in"
            fill="both"
            repeat="0">
        </a-animation>
    </a-text>
</a-scene>
```

If I set a static delay with `begin=5000`, it works fine, but if I try to set it on an event, like `begin="coogeetour"`, the animation doesn't occur. I've tried firing the event two ways:

First, by registering a component for the *scene*, in a script tag *above* the `a-scene` tag, and using `document.querySelector()` identify the text element:

```
<script>
    AFRAME.registerComponent('coogee2006-scene', {

    // emit text events when the scene is initialised
    init: function () {
        console.log('Running coogee2006-scene.init()');
        document.querySelector("#coogee2006-text").emit('coogeetour');
    }
    });
</script>
```

Second, by registering a component for the *text element* and using `this.el`, as in the A-Frame `Writing a Component` section, and putting this in an external file that is linked:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('coogee2006-text', {

  // emit text events when the scene is initialised
  init: function () {
    console.log('Initialising text element');
    this.el.emit('coogeetour');
  }
});
```

In either case, the `console.log` works, so the component is initialising, but the animation isn't happening. I can't find `coogeetour` in the elements' event listeners when debugging, but I don't know if that's because `emit()` isn't working properly or because it oughtn't show up in the debugging.

**EDIT:** here's my console log on loading:

```
Navigated to http://127.0.0.1:4000/private/JoQyfM/
index.js:73A-Frame Version: 0.5.0 (Date 10-02-2017, Commit #110055d)
index.js:74three Version: ^0.83.0
index.js:75WebVR Polyfill Version: dmarcos/webvr-polyfill#a02a8089b
browser.js:117 core:a-assets:warn Asset loading timed out in  +0ms 3000 ms
three.js:19590 THREE.WebGLRenderer 83
(index):81 Running coogee2006-scene.init()
browser.js:117 components:sound:warn All the sounds are playing. If you need to play more sounds simultaneously consider increasing the size of pool with the `poolSize` attribute. +118ms
three.js:17507 THREE.WebGLRenderer: image is not power of two (5980x2990). Resized to 8192x4096 <img crossorigin=​"anonymous" src=​"/​assets/​vr/​sydney-coogee-3-peter-gawthrop.jpg">​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure exactly why, but it looks like the component methods are swallowing the `emit()` event.  I tried putting that same call in the `update()` function but it still did not work.

What did work was to put the emit call in a timeout:

```
setTimeout(function() { document.querySelector("#coogee2006-text").emit('coogeetour'); }, 0);
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/shanabus/pen/zZYBaa

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it looks like `begin` only works with numerical values; `delay` works with both numerical values and event names. To be fair, this is described in the [attribute table](https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/core/animations.html#begin) for animations, but the block below it on the `begin` attribute shows an example of it being used with an event name. Maybe a depreciated attribute?

**EDIT:** okay, maybe this isn't the answer. I'm not entirely sure why `delay` and `begin` both exist—is it so there can be a delay following an event trigger, or is `delay` just depreciated?

Comment: rensa, the docs say *begin* can be an event name, "This can either be a number, representing milliseconds to wait, or an event name to wait for. "

Comment: Yeah, I think this might be a different issue and I was just getting confused with `delay` and `begin`. I'll give your answer a go in a tic!